# sbt Test scope includes Runtime?

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j, log4j2

I'm configuring SLF4J within an SBT application and the Test vs Runtime scopes are working differently than I'd expect.

The setup I want:

- tests (sbt test): use `slf4-simple` as the implementation
- bundle/production runtime (sbt run): use `log4j-slf4j-impl`

Relevant `build.sbt` (sbt 0.13) section:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.25" % Test,
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % 2.8.2 % Runtime,
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % 2.8.2 % Runtime,
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % 2.8.2 % Runtime
```

The error I'm getting is that there are two slf4j bindings present, the log4j one and the simple.

I'm wondering how the Runtime dependencies can be excluded from the Test scope, or if this is the wrong approach here.

To distill the question: I want to use a few different jars at runtime vs test that are mutually exclusive. How can this be done in sbt 0.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Test scope includes Compile and presumably Runtime. So anything you add in Runtime it's also added in Test.

You can try to exclude `log4j-slf4j-impl` from the Test classpath like this:

```
fullClasspath.in(Test) := fullClasspath.in(Test).value.filterNot(_.data.getName.contains("log4j-slf4j-impl"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for this exact concern. However it's the 'presumably Runtime' part I don't get. This seems like a common paradigm, e.g. mysql in prod but h2 in test, different loggers in prod vs test, etc. How is this done in sbt? Seems odd test includes Runtime like this.

Comment: I don't find a lot of libraries to have this classpath binding feature you see with slf4j. Slf4j is a pain to get right, most library authors incorrectly add a binding in their dependencies whereas they shouldn't. They should let me choose if I want log4j, or something else to use. Now if you use h2 for test there is nothing preventing you there. h2 will be visible only in your test code and you will be able to use it with no issue. h2 will not complain that MySQL is in the classpath (nor would MySQL complain about h2). This classpath behavior is explicitly slf4j's.